# Select all rows between two rows of a table

Tags: jquery

I used the following code to select all elements(Table rows) between element1(Selected Table row 1) and element2(Selected Table row 2) , but it gives all the rows of the table and not the only rows between the following two rows.

```
 $("img[alt='Expand']").bind("click", function () {
      var elementUntil1 = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
      var elementUntil2 = elementUntil1.nextAll("tr.SubClassRow:first")
      var betweenElement = $(elementUntil1[0]).nextUntil(elementUntil[0]).andSelf();

});


   <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="SubClassRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="Expand" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="VehicleDetailRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="hidden" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="VehicleDetailRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="hidden" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="SubClassRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="Expand" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="VehicleDetailRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="hidden" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="VehicleDetailRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="hidden" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="SubClassRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="Expand" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="VehicleDetailRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="hidden" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="VehicleDetailRow">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <div class="clickable">
                    <img alt="hidden" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>15-Sep-2001</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you share a sample of your html

Comment: Also, what's referenced by `$(this)`, in your jQuery?

Comment: And what did you want to do with the rows, once they've been found?

Comment: i want to show them , actually the rows having class VehicleDetailRow are hidden

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('img[alt="Expand"]').click(function () {
    var rowsBetween = $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('.subClassRow').filter(':not(".SubClassRow")');
    // use like so:
    rowsBetween.css('visibility', function (i, v) {
        console.log(this, v);
        return v == 'collapse' ? 'visible' : 'collapse';
    }).find('td').toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4kXjP/1/).

References:

- [attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [CSS `visibility` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).
- [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).
- [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Hi this work as mine, but it select all the rows, not only two rows between tr having class 'SubClassRow', in my table I have hundreds of rows

Comment: your example works in the following way when the rows are increasing (see this http://jsfiddle.net/V9kPG/5/). I only want to show the  rows that are between two consecutive rows that has class name as subClassRow